# Finding probability that 2 has appeared atleast once given sum is 10 and die is thrown thrice?

Tags: probability, dice

An unbiased die is thrown three times; the sum of numbers coming up is 10. The probability that two has appeared at least once is:

A 1/36
B 5/36
C 91/216
D 1/18 ?

I was able to find out of 216 possible outcomes of throwing dice thrice only 27 of them give sum ten. Then I counted number of triads where no 2 was there which were 17 and hence the required probability should be 10/27? Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: If you list the 27 possibilities, you'll see how many times out of that 27 you have a $2$ showing.

Comment: hint: the number of twos can only be 2 or 1 (since 3*2=6<10 and 0*2 is prohibited)  if its 2, how many possibilities has the third dice? if its 1, how many possibilities have the remaining 2 dice? now just add up

Comment: As you see from John's answer, the possible number groups occur in sets of three or six (depending on whether two of the values are equal or not) - so your mistake looks like a counting error. The fact that none of the multiple choice answers look right might indicate that you have the question slightly wrong.

Comment: Is it correct that 27 is no of outcomes where sum is 10 ?

Comment: Yes, $27$ is correct.  I ran an Excel sheet to check all $216$ possibilities.  But now I'm wondering why my answer isn't among the choices.

Comment: Edited my answer with another possibility for what the question is asking (though if that's the case it's really poorly worded).

Comment: @john yes I think you are correct it wants us to see both the conditions as one!! Thanks it helped!

Comment: @Raghav: That's definitely not what this question is asking. Either you copied it wrong or it was posed wrong. It's not just badly worded; it's very clearly worded to ask a different question.

Comment: No I did not copy it wrong ! The question as well as the options are correct. It is not conditional probability they are asking. If it was so then the denominator must be 27 or some number divisible by it, but each of the denominators in the options are 216 or some number divisible by it. Hence the required answer must be option D.

Comment: Also C cannot be answer though the denominator is 216 which is divisible by 27 as we cannot have any common factor between the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 4):

From the $27$ possibilities it's just a matter of counting the ones with at least one $2$.

$$[631] \times 6, [622] \times 3, [541] \times 6, [532] \times 6, [442] \times 3,[433] \times 3$$

So ... $(3+6+3)/27 = 4/9$.

One possibility for another answer (though this doesn't really seem to be what the question is asking) is the probability of the sum being $10$ *and* having at least one $2$.  Then this would be $12/216 = 1/18$, which is choice (D).  But, again, the wording of the question really appears to say that we know the sum is $10$.